# uber cadence :: want to store an object inside a workflow

Tags: uber-api, cadence-workflow, temporal-workflow

Want to store an object inside a workflow then want to receive it through cadence api.

```
ListOpenWorkflowExecutionsRequest listOpenWorkflowExecutionsRequest=new ListOpenWorkflowExecutionsRequest();
listOpenWorkflowExecutionsRequest.setDomain(DOMAIN);
listOpenWorkflowExecutionsRequest.setStartTimeFilter(startTimeFilter);
ListOpenWorkflowExecutionsResponse response=
        cadenceService.ListOpenWorkflowExecutions(listOpenWorkflowExecutionsRequest);*
```

I am open to go with any solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `QueryWorkflowExecution` API to retrieve information from a single workflow.

The *list* API is used to get lists of workflows without querying them directly. You can attach custom information (called memo) to a visibility record that is returned by a list API. Use `WorkflowOptions.memo` property to add it.

The memo is not indexable. If you want the ability to index on custom attributes use the [Search Attributes](https://docs.temporal.io/docs/learn-workflow-filtering) feature. One other feature of search attributes is that they are updatable from the workflow code using `upsertSearchAttributes` API. So for example, if the workflow code updates the "state" attribute on each state transition then it would be possible to find all the workflows in a given state. Also, all the search attributes are returned by the list API so their value can be shown in the UI list view even if they are not part of the search predicate. Note that this requires Elastic Search cluster integration enabled.

Comment: Thanks, but I am querying the internal state of the workflow. For example, the state isApproved or isPending in my workflow that is not a part of cadence workflow. I can get them by calling individual workflow through @QueryMethod which I want to avoid because it impacts performance as in my case I have to return a list.

Comment: Updated with search attributes info